# Error in sending mail through smtps

Tags: java, email, ssl-certificate, smtps

I am getting the below exception while connecting to my mailserver while executing the below line

```
transport.connect("test.mailserver.com",465,"test.user@test.com","testpwd");
```

The Exception is:

```
(javax.mail.MessagingException) javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: subject/issuer name chaining check failed
```

below is the code:

```
protected static Session initializeSession(MailMessage p_msg) throws Exception{

    //Get the SMTP Host
    Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.put( "mail.smtps.host", "test.mailserver.com" );
    prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    prop.put("mail.smtps.auth", true);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,null);
    session.setDebug( p_msg.getDebugMode() );
    return session;
}   
protected static void sendMessage(MimeMessage p_msg)  throws Exception{

    Properties prop = System.getProperties();

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("test.mailserver.com",465,"test.user@test.com","testpwd");
    transport.sendMessage(p_msg, p_msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dimly recall running into something like this myself.  It turned out that I had configured SSL incorrectly by putting the certificates in the server's certificate chain in the wrong order.  The SSL stacks in a typical web browser don't care about this, but (apparently) the client-side SSL engine in Java cannot (or will not) cope with a server that presents the chain in the wrong order.

So, if you get no luck with other answers, try looking at the way that you have installed the SSL certificate, etc on your mail server.

Answer (score 0):

For sending an email from java, you need below jars:

- **`mail.jar`**
- **`geronimo-javamail-transport-1.1.1.jar`**
- **`geronimo-javamail_1.3.1_spec-1.1.jar`**

Please try to use below method to send an email from java. This method will send an email using SSL authentication. In the below method, there is three parameters:
List recipients : list all recipients of this mail.
subject: subject of this mail
messageToSend: message body of the mail.

```
public void sendMail(List<String> recipents,String subject,String messageToSend)
    {
        setParameters();
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
            {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Your GmailID,your GMAIL Password);
                }
            });
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSender(addressFrom);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(messageToSend, "text/plain");

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipents.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipents.size(); i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipents.get(i));
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            transport.connect();
            transport.send(message);
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Kandarp, Thanx for ur reply.. i added both jars which u mentioned.

Comment: I added both the jars which u have mentioned and tried ur code its throwing an exception "Error connecting to smtp.gmail.com, 465" for gmail and when i tried this for my mail server its throwing the same previous exception (javax.mail.MessagingException) javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: subject/issuer name chaining check failed